# Custom first-child in Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>teste1</td>
    <td>teste2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With a custom CSS:

```
tr:first-child {
    color: #696969;
    background-color: black; !important;
}
```

The color is applied, but the `background-color`, isn't. Why? With `last-child` the `background-color` works. Thanks.

Update: If I remove the `table-striped` it works. But I need to keep it.

Update2: `table-striped` Bootstrap CSS:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, it's selector problem, 
The selector B3 using is more specific, now, place your css as sequence as below.
Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
```

and add this css in the custom.css

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:first-child > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:first-child > th {
    color: #696969;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

I've tested and the result is what you need.
http://jsfiddle.net/TAp7T/1/

Comment: I have the css in that order. My way or your way only works in IE. Doesn't work on FF and Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how the notification work, but here's to tell you that I just updated it

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
background-color: black; !important;
```

To

```
background-color: black !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need important just add more classes or an id to the selector to make it work like this and apply your style to the `td`.

```
table.table-condensed.table.table-striped tr:first-child td{
    color: #696969;
    background-color: black;
}
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amdorra/3a8PJ/1/)

Comment: Just updated the post. There is something about the `table-striped` in Bootstrap. In a 'normal' css world... it should works.

Comment: i think it's not working because you are adding a tbody there that's not in the html

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of `!important`, the CSS style gets applied to `first-child` or `last-child`. See in [JSFiddle first](http://jsfiddle.net/HTNcW/1/) for `first-child` and [JSFiddle last](http://jsfiddle.net/HTNcW/2/) for `last-child`. Probably, you have shown only a part of your project, so we can only analyze based on the info you have given. The code really applies the `background-color` to any child.

Comment: Just updated the post. There is something about the `table-striped` in Bootstrap. In a 'normal' css world... it should works.